# JavaScript: write a function that edits a string within a range

Tags: javascript

I wanted to write out a function to edit a string from a certain range, and potentially swap another piece of string for that range if provided.
The range works like this - the start index is inclusive and end index is exclusive (like `slice`) and if the range is bigger than the length of the string then it selects up to the end. if the start index is out of the range of the string then the entire operation is ignored.
For example,

```js
const string = 'HELLO'
const startIdx = 1
const endIdx = 3

editText(string, startIdx, endIdx) // should return 'HLO'
```

```js
const string = 'HELLO'
const startIdx = 1
const endIdx = 3
const textToAdd = 'y there'

editText(string, startIdx, endIdx) // 'HLO'
```

```js
const string = 'HELLO'
const startIdx = 2
const endIdx = 6
const textToAdd = 'y there'
editText(string, startIdx, endIdx,textToAdd)  // 'HEy there'
```

here is my attempt:

```js
function editText(string, startIdx, endIdx, textToAdd) {
    if(startIdx < 0 || startIdx >= string.length) return string
    const strArr = string.split('')
    if(textToAdd) {
        strArr.splice(startIdx, endIdx - startIdx, textToAdd)
    } else {
        strArr.splice(startIdx, endIdx - startIdx)
    }

    return strArr.join('')
}
```

It works fine but I wonder if there is any more efficient or more elegant way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can just use `string.replace`

try like this :

```
function editText(string, startIdx, endIdx, textToAdd=null) {
    if(startIdx < 0 || startIdx >= string.length) return string
   return string.replace(string.substring(startIdx, endIdx), textToAdd || "")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I like solution with `string.replace` from above.

Another approach will be to use `string.slice` based on start/end provided index and optional text:

```js
function editText(str, start, end, extraText = '') {
    return str.slice(0, start) + extraText + str.slice(end, str.length);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this doesn't work right. Try the examples I gave in the description and you can easily verify that.

Comment: Interesting, I've tested them, and they are looks good to me, I've created fiddle to have some proofs: https://jsfiddle.net/79n5za6b/1/
Also, can you double check your second example, you are declared `textToAdd ` but you are not using it in your function as argument, is that expected? Since first and second example are identical in this case.

Comment: sorry I guess I didn't make my question description clear enough. It is going to *insert* that ``textToAdd` into the original string given proper indexes. Like, if you have const `string = 'HELLO'` `const startIdx = 2` `const endIdx = 3` `const textToAdd = 'y there'` `editText(string, startIdx, endIdx,textToAdd)` should give you `HEy thereLO` as @Belhadjer Samir's answer outputs

Comment: I see, yeah, now it makes more sense, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I've updated fiddle, based on your requirements, just in case:
https://jsfiddle.net/fuv62egz/